# insertion into hive table from shell script using oozie

Tags: oozie

I am using Oozie for automate the process.when i am using simple load data using shell script from oozie then all the data get inserted into hive tables.but when i am inserting values from a table to another table using shell scripting then oozie job gets killed automatically.Dont know why...

Error logs:

```
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:44 +0000] access       WARNING  10.23.227.121 hdfs - "GET /logs HTTP/1.1"
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:42 +0000] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: Could not find job application_1426676094899_0051.: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/usr/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/views.py", line 61, in decorate raise PopupException(_('Could not find job %s.') % jobid, detail=e)    PopupException: Could not find job application_1426676094899_0051.
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:42 +0000] resource     DEBUG    GET Got response: {"job":{"submitTime":1426690455158,"startTime":-1,"finishTime":1426690462073,"id":"job_1426676094899_0051","name":"insert into table ide...ecision.currency_dim(Stage-1)","queue":"default","user":"hdfs","state":"FAILED","mapsTotal":0,"mapsCompleted":0,"reducesTotal":0,"reducesCompleted":0,"uberized":false,"diagnostics":"Job init failed : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://inhyicbivm021.techmahindra.com:8020/user/hdfs/.staging/job_1426676...
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:42 +0000] resource     DEBUG    GET Got response: {"app":{"id":"application_1426676094899_0051","user":"hdfs","name":"insert into table ide...ecision.currency_dim(Stage-1)","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"FAILED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://inhyicbivm021.techmahindra.com:8088/proxy/application_1426676094899_0051/jobhistory/job/job_1426676094899_0051","diagnostics":"Job init failed : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://inhyicbivm021.t...
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:42 +0000] access       INFO     10.23.227.121 hdfs - "GET /jobbrowser/jobs/application_1426676094899_0051 HTTP/1.1"
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:41 +0000] resource     DEBUG    GET Got response: {"apps":{"app":[{"id":"application_1426676094899_0043","user":"hdfs","name":"insert into table ide...ecision.currency_dim(Stage-1)","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"FAILED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://inhyicbivm021.techmahindra.com:8088/proxy/application_1426676094899_0043/jobhistory/job/job_1426676094899_0043","diagnostics":"Job init failed : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://inhyic...
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:41 +0000] access       INFO     10.23.227.121 hdfs - "GET /jobbrowser/ HTTP/1.1"
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:40 +0000] access       INFO     10.23.227.121 hdfs - "GET /jobbrowser/ HTTP/1.1"
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:40 +0000] middleware   DEBUG    No desktop_app known for request.
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:40 +0000] thrift_util  DEBUG    Thrift call <class 'TCLIService.TCLIService.Client'>.CloseOperation returned in 0ms: TCloseOperationResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=None, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, infoMessages=None, statusCode=0))
[18/Mar/2015 08:01:40 +0000] thrift_util  DEBUG    Thrift call: <class 'TCLIService.TCLIService.Client'>.CloseOperation(args=(TCloseOperationReq(operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=4, operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='\x89w\xccf\x84:G\xda\xa9GR0\x00\xc8G\x96', guid='J\xcb\xa7\xba|\xfaH\x93\x93\xba$\x02\t\xc0IE'))),), kwargs={})
```

need help.....

Comment: Can you post the rest of the line containing `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://inhyic...`? It seems like that might have something to do with your issue.

Comment: That is not visible actually.What i got from error log i have posted here.